# Pandas iterate function through data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm relatively new to Python and functions. I'm attempting to iterate the following function through each row of a dataframe and append the computed result for each row to a new column:

```
def manhattan_distance(x,y):

  return sum(abs(a-b) for a,b in zip(x,y))
```

For reference, this is the dataframe I'm testing on:

```
entries = [
{'age1':'2', 'age2':'2'},
{'age1':'12', 'age2': '12'},
{'age1':'5', 'age2': '50'}
]

df=pd.DataFrame(entries)

df['age1'] = df['age1'].astype(str).astype(int)
df['age2'] = df['age2'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

I've seen this answer [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas) and have got as far as this:

```
import itertools
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    df['distance']=df.apply(lambda row: manhattan_distance(row['age1'], row['age2']), axis=1)
```

Which returns the following:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------      ----
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call  last)
<ipython-input-42-aa6a21cd1de9> in <module>()
      4 #    print (manhattan_distance(row['age1'],row['age2']))
      5 
----> 6     df['distance']=df.apply(lambda row:    manhattan_distance(row['age1'], row['age2']), axis=1)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in   apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)
   4852                         f, axis,
   4853                         reduce=reduce,
-> 4854                         ignore_failures=ignore_failures)
   4855             else:
   4856                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures, reduce)
   4948             try:
   4949                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
-> 4950                     results[i] = func(v)
   4951                     keys.append(v.name)
   4952             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-42-aa6a21cd1de9> in <lambda>(row)
      4 #    print (manhattan_distance(row['age1'],row['age2']))
      5 
----> 6     df['distance']=df.apply(lambda row:     manhattan_distance(row['age1'], row['age2']), axis=1)

<ipython-input-36-74da75398c4c> in manhattan_distance(x, y)
      1 def manhattan_distance(x,y):
      2 
----> 3   return sum(abs(a-b) for a,b in zip(x,y))
      4  #   return sum(abs(a-b) for a,b in map(lambda x: zip(a,b)))

TypeError: ('zip argument #1 must support iteration', 'occurred at index 0')
```

Based on other responses to the question I referred above, I have attempted to amend the zip statement in my function:

```
import itertools
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    df['distance']=df.apply(lambda row: manhattan_distance(row['age1'], row['age2']), axis=1)
```

The above returns this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call  last)
<ipython-input-44-aa6a21cd1de9> in <module>()
      4 #    print (manhattan_distance(row['age1'],row['age2']))
      5 
----> 6     df['distance']=df.apply(lambda row:   manhattan_distance(row['age1'], row['age2']), axis=1)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)
   4852                         f, axis,
   4853                         reduce=reduce,
-> 4854                         ignore_failures=ignore_failures)
   4855             else:
   4856                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures, reduce)
   4948             try:
   4949                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
-> 4950                     results[i] = func(v)
   4951                     keys.append(v.name)
   4952             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-44-aa6a21cd1de9> in <lambda>(row)
      4 #    print (manhattan_distance(row['age1'],row['age2']))
      5 
----> 6     df['distance']=df.apply(lambda row:  manhattan_distance(row['age1'], row['age2']), axis=1)

<ipython-input-43-5daf167baf5f> in manhattan_distance(x, y)
      2 
      3 #  return sum(abs(a-b) for a,b in zip(x,y))
----> 4    return sum(abs(a-b) for a,b in map(lambda x: zip(a,b)))

TypeError: ('map() must have at least two arguments.', 'occurred at index 0')
```

If this is the right approach take, I'm unclear what my map() arguments need to be for the function to work.

Comment: What would be the desired output? How do you compare two characters?

Comment: Could you please provide a formula to calculate the manhattan distance of two given values for `age1` and `age2`. How is the manhattan distance of two values defined, since I only find definitions for at least four values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

entries = [
{'age1':'2', 'age2':'2'},
{'age1':'12', 'age2': '12'},
{'age1':'5', 'age2': '50'}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(entries)
df['age1'] = df['age1'].astype(str).astype(int)
df['age2'] = df['age2'].astype(str).astype(int)

def manhattan_distance(row):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry#Formal_definition
    return np.sum(abs(row['age1']-row['age2']))

df['distance'] = df.apply(manhattan_distance, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Comment: But here it makes no sense to `np.sum(..)` since `abs(..)` returns only *one* element.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: You're right. However, I wanted to show an approach for the general definition of Manhattan Distance which itself needs to sum up the difference of `p_i - q_i`